# How to have a function have different return type? C++

Tags: c++, return-type

I am doing an assignment and my prof gave us this task as part of the assignment. I am still relatively new to C++ so any help. I created the function however I don't understand how he wants to return a blank string if nothing is found but return an integer if it is found. Is that possible somehow without overloading functions? Right now I just have the function set to an integer type and instead of returning a blank string it returns 0 instead.

Here is the task that is part of the assignment. If you could explain your solution so that a dumb person like me can understand it that would be much appreciated.

**FindWord** – this member function will take a string as a parameter and search for it within the
list. If the list is empty or it cannot be found, it returns a blank string value (“”). Otherwise, it
returns the int value of the index (e.g. the array element number, such as 0, 1, 2, etc.).
Remember that the == equality comparison operator works on strings that are handled as string
objects (rather than char data elements) and that you do not need to be case sensitive.

EDIT: Here is my code I have so far

```
int WordList::FindWord(string word){

if ((listSize = 0)){ // return -1 if no list exists;
    return -1;
}
else {
    for (int i =0;i<listSize;i++){ // run loop to check for word/        
        if (word == list[i]) // if word is found then return index
            return i;
     }        
        return -1; // return -1 if word is not found
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you would show us what you have tried, rather than just copying in your assignment.

Comment: This is a very bad assignment... returning -1 or `npos`, OK, but a blank string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: No that's not possible. Either you've misunderstood what you are being asked to do, or your teacher is an idiot. I suggest you ask your teacher, can't see how SO can help you.

Comment: You can check out `std::variant` for this, although i agree with the above commenters, that this assignment is not the best for teaching c++, because is confusing.
I recommend returning an invalid position, like -1, for signaling that the string was not found.

Comment: in c++ every function has signature - types of parameters and type of return value, so you can not return in one case string and int in another. that being said, you can return something like std::any. what you are doing is (or very look like) std::find, so you can check how it works (and i'd assume most people will find it easier to read your code if you follow "style" of standard library)

Comment: There is one "exceptional" way to return objects of another type than the declared return type, and that is to throw an exception. And technically, you _can_ `throw "";`. It is syntactically correct. But it's not good style. A more appropriate object to throw here would be `std::invalid_argument`.

Comment: I wonder at what level of programming the assignment is supposed to be completed. Would it be sufficient to return the integer value as a string, using `std::to_string`? While the assignment does specify `int` it does seem like a bizarre assignment. I think it would be worth discussing with the prof.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with C++17 features `std::variant` and `std::get_if`.

- The search function will return `std::variant<int, std::string>`
- In `main` use `std::get_if` to determine which of the values has been returned.

`std::get_if` returns pointer to the value stored in the pointed-to variant or null pointer on error.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

 std::variant<int, std::string> strSearch(const std::string& searchStr, const std::list<std::string>& searchList)
 {
     int i = 0;
     for(const auto& s: searchList) {               
        if(!s.find(searchStr))
            return i;
        i++;    
     }
     return "";     
 }

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> strList = {"stack", "stackover", "stackoverflow"};
    std::string str = "stackoverflow";
    std::variant<int, std::string> v{strSearch(str, strList)};
    if(std::get_if<int>(&v))
        std::cout << "String found. Index in the List is:" << std::get<int>(v) << '\n';
    else    
        std::cout << "String not found"  << '\n';

    str = "stackunderflow";
    v = strSearch(str, strList);
    if(std::get_if<int>(&v))
        std::cout << "String found. Index in the List is:" << std::get<int>(v)  << '\n';
    else    
        std::cout << "String not found."  << '\n';    

}
```

See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74e47d94963a9aef).

Comment: If it was C++17, then I would go for an optional, not returning an empty string.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: The problem here is the teacher's artificial requirement. Within those constraints, this is the best answer. But I bet the teacher did not expect this answer - the phrasing of the question tells us that the teacher is not actually that familiar with C++.

Comment: I know about the quality of the question, see my comment to the question.

Comment: @SirCobalt: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return two objects, and you cannot do this by overloading the function.

So you can use:

```
std::pair<int, std::string> search(const std::string&, const std::list<std::string>& l);
```

Or you can return the second object by passing a reference to it:

```
std::string search(const std::string&, const std::list<std::string>& l, it& index);
```

Another option in C++17 is the proper way of doing this:

```
std::optional<size_t> search(const std::string&, const std::list<std::string>& l);
```

You get an integer if the search was successful, otherwise you don't get a value. Returning an empty string is just...

Comment: Seems unlikely to be what the question is asking for. How would you tell which of the two return values applies?

Comment: Easy. The return for the string could be the string that you passed in, so you know if you get an empty string or not, and if it's the original string, you go for the integer.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible within C++, Only one return type can be defined for a function.

There are 2 possible scenarios here:

## 1 Return a struct containing both an integer and a string and using the one that is set

E.G

```
struct returnData{
int returnCode;
std::string returnText;
}

returnData myFunc(std::string){}
```

2 would be using your search string potentially as an in/out parameter but this makes even less sense than the assignment so I won't go into it.

There's also the possibility of returning a void* ( a generic piece of data) and then casting it to a string or int but there would be no way to know which it should be.

I really don't know what exactly your professor is expecting from this assignment since returning a different value based on a parameter is literally impossible unless you're returning them both and ignoring one.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an answer suggesting structure to be returned. How about union with integer and string values and place it as a return type

Comment: How would the caller know which item in the union has been filled in?

Comment: That's a valid question. I found some answers here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194506/how-to-know-that-which-variable-from-union-is-used

Answer (score -1):

you can return void*, it will return everything you want

Comment: brr, that's a chilling option.