# How to return multiple types from a member method

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a class method that can return any one member variable value based on value held in DataType struct variable. I have tried below code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    int DataType;/* holds enum value for one of below data data needs to be returned  */
    union /* value of var is one of these needs to be returned */
    {
       int32_t x;
       uint32_t y;
       uint64_t mz;
       bool    b;
       struct         
       {
          char* ptr;
          int len;    
       } str;              
    }data;
};


struct A a1 = { /* value 1 means int32_t, 2 means uint32_t, 3 means uint64_t , 4 means bool and 5 means str */ 2, 32};
//struct A a2 = { /* value 1 means int32_t, 2 means uint32_t, 3 means uint64_t , 4 means bool and 5 means str */ 5, {{ "Hello",5}}};
class B
{
public:
   B(){}

   template <>
   T GetVar(struct A a0)
   {
      if (a0.DataType == 2)
         return a0.data.y;
      if (a0.DataType == 5)
         return std::string(a0.data.str.ptr);
      return 0;
   }
};

int main()
{
  B b1;
  auto d = b1.GetVar(a1);
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
  //auto d1 = b1.GetVar(a2);
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

I get compilation error - and I know that error is related to initializing the **str** member variable of **struct A** (how to solve this) and also how can the class method return different variable values?

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 try72.cpp
try72.cpp:26:11: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class B'
 template <>
           ^
try72.cpp:27:1: error: 'T' does not name a type
 T GetVar(struct A a0)
 ^
try72.cpp: In function 'int main()':
try72.cpp:40:13: error: 'class B' has no member named 'GetVar'
 auto d = b1.GetVar(a1);
             ^
try72.cpp:42:14: error: 'class B' has no member named 'GetVar'
 auto d1 = b1.GetVar(a2);
              ^
try72.cpp:42:21: error: 'a2' was not declared in this scope
 auto d1 = b1.GetVar(a2);

                 ^
```

Comment: The compiler is correct, you never declare `T` anywhere. And you can't return different types from a single function anyway. You might want to look into [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). Or perhaps even use a `union` for the returned value as well?

Comment: @Programmer: You can check out my answer written for a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590671/how-to-have-a-function-have-different-return-type-c/53591616#53591616.

Comment: @P.W - thanks but std::variant is in C++ 17 and I am using C++11 - is there a way I can achieve the objective?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude std::any is also from C++17 - is there anything equivalent in C++11

Comment: Then your only solution is either the Boost library (`boost::variant` or `boost::any`) or unions.

Comment: @Programmer: I agree with SomeProgrammerDude's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I was able to resolve BTW how can I initialize my struct A -> str member variable - I tried had but not able to achieve it?

Comment: @P.W - how can I check that type of the data returned by the function returning bost::variant - if in case some one changes that method in my code I need to ensure that data type should be one of the listed one only?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is it possible to check what data type the function returned so that before continuing my flow we can validate the type the function returned?

Answer (score 0):

A function has **one** return type. You need different functions to return values of different types.

(in C++17 you can make it look like you are returning different types from a function, but it's actually a template that's instantiated differently for various values)

If you want to choose what to do based on the contained type of your union, you can instead take inspiration from `std::variant`, and accept a function object with multiple `operator()`s, one for each possible type.

```
template <typename Return>
struct AVisitor
{
    virtual Return operator()(int32_t) const = 0;
    virtual Return operator()(uint32_t) const = 0;
    virtual Return operator()(uint64_t) const = 0;
    virtual Return operator()(bool) const = 0;
    virtual Return operator()(std::string) const = 0;
};

template <typename Return>
Return visit(const A & a, const AVisitor<Return> & visitor)
{
    switch (a.DataType)
    {
         case 1: return visitor(a.data.x);
         case 2: return visitor(a.data.y);
         case 3: return visitor(a.data.mz);
         case 4: return visitor(a.data.b);
         case 5: return visitor(std::string(a.data.str.ptr));
    }
}

struct cout_visitor : AVisitor<void>
{
    void operator()(int32_t x) const { std::cout << x; }
    void operator()(uint32_t y) const { std::cout << y; }
    void operator()(uint64_t mz) const { std::cout << mz; }
    void operator()(bool b) const { std::cout << b; }
    void operator()(std::string str) const { std::cout << str; }
}

int main()
{
    cout_visitor vis;
    visit(a1, vis);
    visit(a2, vis);
}
```

Although the obvious alternative to that would be to define `A` as `using A =` (`std::` or `boost::`) `variant<int32_t, uint32_t, uint64_t, bool, std::string>;`